# React-Redux. При клике стейт обновляется, а таблица с данными - нет

Tags: reactjs, redux

У меня в приложении рендерится вот такая таблица

```js
let OurBody = ({ filteredArr }) => {

  return (
    <tbody>
      {filteredArr.map(element =>
        <tr key={element._id}>
          <td>{element.company}</td>
          <td>{element.balance}</td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </tbody>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    filteredArr: getSortedCompanies(state.json, state.sortCompany)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OurBody);
```

Компонент заголовка таблицы. При срабатывании onClick моя функция сортирует данные в стейте. Подписался на обновления стейта, вывел в консоль - всё красиво, всё корректно.

```js
let Headersort = ({ dispatch }) => (
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td onClick={() => {dispatch(sortCompany());}}>Company</td>
   <td>Balance</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
 Arr: state.json,
  })

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Headersort);
```

Главный компонент

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, error } = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
    }
  
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <Headersort />
        <OurBody />
      </table>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
  
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.loading,
  error: state.error
})

App = connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
  
export default App;
```

Компонент с функцией сортировки данных, через которую проходит json с данными, а затем передается в компонент OurBody:

```js
    //getSortedCompanies
  
export default (json, sortCompany) => {
    if(sortCompany===null) {
        return json;
    }

    else if(sortCompany)
        return json.sort( (a,b) => {
            if (a.company.toLowerCase() < b.company.toLowerCase()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        });

    else {
        return json.sort( (a,b) => {
            if (a.company.toLowerCase() > b.company.toLowerCase()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

По клику всё что нужно меняется, редьюсер отрабатывает, стейт Redux-а обновляется, но таблица рендерится только один раз. После этого она не обновляется. Хотя при обновлении стейта вся страница должна обновляться. Причем проблема не в данных, нигде никаких ошибок нет. Отдельно вывел таблицу с уже отсортированными данными, всё отрисовалось без ошибок.
Если для анализа нужны будут другие компоненты - добавлю и их.

P.S. Обновил ссылку на гитхаб (старая ссылка не работала) https://github.com/DrGreenNow/React-Redux-Table

Comment: Клик по отрендереннтой таблице? Если да, то это типичная ошибка при работе с js. Надо после перезаписи таблицы снова привязывать клик по ней к обработчику.

Comment: Фактически да, клик по отрендеренной таблице. А как заново привязать клик к обработчику?

Comment: Я не очень силен в реакт, поэтому пусть кто-то другой поправит код. В ES6 я создаю метод bindEvents(), который вызываю в конструкторе и после обновления элементов, на которых висел клик.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это реакт, он сам навешивает обработчик - не надо ничего перепривязывать

Comment: @AndreyGreen отдебагайте mapStateToProps, проверьте, что ваша функция сортировки действительно возвращает другой объект

Comment: Я  подписался на обновления стора Redux-а и вижу, что при каждом клике структура стора остается точно такой же, только массив с ключом json сортируется по возрастанию, а затем по убыванию. А таблица эти изменения данных не подтягивает.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Проблема была в самой функции сортировки. Вот правильный вариант.

```js
export default (json, sortCompany) => {
    if (sortCompany === null) {
      console.log(sortCompany);
      return json;
    } else if (sortCompany) {
      console.log(sortCompany);
      return [...json].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.company.toLowerCase() < b.company.toLowerCase()) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      });
    } else {
      return [...json].sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.company.toLowerCase() > b.company.toLowerCase()) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return -1;
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

В чем именно была причина, еще не знаю, мне прислали уже рабочий код, чуть позже буду изучать и рассматривать.